# add subitems to a listview

Tags: vb.net, listview, backgroundworker

I'm using a backgroundworker to populate a listview, but i want to add subitems also. Can anyone help me out?

```
    Public Class Form1

    Private Sub bgw_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bgw.DoWork
        Dim li As New List(Of ListViewItem)

        For Each fn As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles("s:\Videos", FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories, "*.*")
            li.Add(New ListViewItem(My.Computer.FileSystem.GetName(fn))) 
            'here i want to add a subitem containing the filesize
            'My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(fn).Length
        Next

        e.Result = li.ToArray
    End Sub

    Private Sub bgw_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles bgw.RunWorkerCompleted
        lv.Items.AddRange(DirectCast(e.Result, ListViewItem()))
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        bgw.RunWorkerAsync()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in your `For Each` loop:

```
Dim NewItem as New ListViewItem(My.Computer.FileSystem.GetName(fn))
NewItem.SubItems.Add(My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(fn).Length)

li.Add(NewItem)
```

Hopefully that should do the trick

Comment: that worked just fine, but how can I add the data using bgw_ProgressChanged?

Comment: Have a look at this link - At the examples section... It should point you in the right direction: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx

Answer (score 1):

this is working too, but is it correct?

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim item1 As String = ""
    Dim item2 As String = ""

    Private Sub bgw_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bgw.DoWork
        Dim progress As Integer = 0
        'calculate progress later
        progress = 1

        For Each fn As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles("s:\Videos", FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories, "*.*")
            item1 = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetName(fn)
            item2 = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(fn).Length

            bgw.ReportProgress(progress)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub bgw_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles bgw.ProgressChanged
        Dim li As New ListViewItem
        li = lv.Items.Add(item1, 0)
        li.SubItems.Add(item2)
    End Sub

    Private Sub bgw_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles bgw.RunWorkerCompleted
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        lv.Items.Clear()
        bgw.RunWorkerAsync()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: ... I'm not seeing where you're updating your listview with the new items... What you're going to want to do is create a list of `ListViewItem` in your `bgw_DoWork`, then every once in a while pass that list to your `bgw_ProgressChanged` where it adds it to your listview. It wouldn't make sense to pass the listview item every iteration of your `for` loop since then you're not really getting any benefit from the backgroundworker...